# Marshaling structure to single line of string

Tags: c#, structure, marshalling, unmarshalling, object-to-string

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public class Comarea
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 1)]
    public string status;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5)]
    public string operationName;
}

public static void StringToObject(string buffer, out Comarea comarea)
{
    IntPtr pBuf = Marshal.StringToBSTR(buffer);
    comarea = (Comarea)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pBuf, typeof(Comarea));
}
```

I can create object from single line of string but I can not do opposite of that.

How can I do that operation?

```
public static void ObjectToString(out string buffer, Comarea comarea)
{
     ???
}
```

It throws exception "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

```
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(comarea);
IntPtr pBuf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(comarea, pBuf, false);
buffer = Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(pBuf); //Error
```

Comment: Your struct is not a BSTR by a long mile.  A BSTR has a *length* field that indicates how long the string is.  That's of course missing, it will read garbage data and is thus likely to bomb.  Very unclear why you need to do this.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how I solved my problem: I used char array and `Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pBuf, size)`

```
public static void ObjectToString(out string buffer, Comarea comarea)
{
    int size = 0;
    IntPtr pBuf = IntPtr.Zero;

    try
    {
        size = Marshal.SizeOf(comarea);
        pBuf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(comarea, pBuf, false);
        buffer = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pBuf, size).Substring(0, size/2); // Answer
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pBuf);
    }
}





[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct Comarea
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
    private char[] status;

    public string Status
    {
        get
        {
            return new string(status);
        }

        set
        {
            status = value.ToFixedCharArray(1);
        }
    }

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5)]
    private char[] operationName;

    public string OperationName
    {
        get
        {
            return new string(operationName);
        }

        set
        {
            operationName = value.ToFixedCharArray(5);
        }
    }
}



public static class FormatterExtensions
{
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static char[] ToFixedCharArray(this string inputString, int arrayLength)
    {
        char[] outputArray = new char[arrayLength];
        char[] inputArray = inputString.ToSafeTrim().ToCharArray();

        if (inputArray.Length == arrayLength)
        {
            return inputArray;
        }
        else
        {
            int i = 0;

            while (i < arrayLength)
            {
                if (i < inputArray.Length)
                {
                    outputArray[i] = inputArray[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }

                i++;
            }

            return outputArray;
        }
    }
}
```

It is so useful for IBM CICS communication(For Commarea)

Answer (score 1):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public class Comarea
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 1)]
    public string status;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5)]
    public string operationName;
}
```

That is laid out as 6 adjacent 16 bit `wchar_t` character elements. So, right off the bat,

```
public static void StringToObject(string buffer, out Comarea comarea)
{
    IntPtr pBuf = Marshal.StringToBSTR(buffer);
    comarea = (Comarea)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pBuf, typeof(Comarea));
}
```

is wrong. Beyond the fact that you leak a `BSTR`, your struct is not a `BSTR`.

You can implement it like this:

```
public static void StringToObject(string buffer, out Comarea comarea)
{
    comarea.status = buffer.Substring(0, 1);
    comarea.operationName = buffer.Substring(1, 5);
}
```

This is under the assumption that the six characters are the contained the the locations implied by the `Substring` calls.

In the opposite direction you write:

```
public static void ObjectToString(out string buffer, Comarea comarea)
{
     buffer = comarea.status + comarea.operationName;
}
```

---

Note that the struct definition must be wrong however

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 1)]
public string status;
```

The marshaller always adds a null-terminator when using `ByValTStr`. So with `SizeConst` of `1`, status will always be marshaled as an empty string. Without actually seeing the unmanaged struct definition, I would not care to tell you how to fix this problem.